# Error running daughter Vue.js app in Asp.net microservices

Tags: .net, vue.js, iis, .net-core, microservices

Both apps work fine when being run as the only Website, but when I place them as daughter applications of a website, I get :

The server has not found anything matching the requested URI (Uniform Resource Identifier).
GET - https://localhost/js/app.afbeb659.js

I've tried changing the script src to /example1/js/chunk.... and the error goes away, but the spa apps still aren't served to the client.

This is what the folder/app structure looks like in IIS:
[image: IIS structre]

What am I missing?

Comment: Based on you structure, the service should be accessed from http://localhost/applicationanem/...  How did you set the spa rootpath? And what error message are you getting now?

Comment: @JokiesDing Correct me if I'm wrong, you mean I should be accessing the service @ localhost/example1?  

the spa rootpath is set like this:
 services.AddSpaStaticFiles(options => options.RootPath = "/client-app/dist");

I have changed the access in the index.html found @client-app/dist and I'm not getting an error anymore, but I'm not getting a website either.    Also, when I have the index.html edited to get rid of those errors, I can see that the app.js etc... files have been loaded, but do not display on the page, and the <no-script> tag is being hit.

Comment: Are you hosting something like asp.net core vue.js template? If so did you register handler in your root web.config? Otherwise, IIS won't return a correct site response.

Comment: @JokiesDing Yes, it's a template like that.  I didn't register a handler, other than the one that was originally published by VS2019.  This is what I have in web.config for handlers 

<handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>

Comment: Have you installed .net core web hosting bundle?

Comment: yes, I've also installed url-rewrite

Comment: Please set url rewrite rule to example/index.html for no file no directory. Then try to acess example/